# What is happening with Max pool backward in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am a little confused with the max pool backward implementation in here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/maxpooling_op_gpu.cu.cc#L192

Can anybody explain how the gradients are being calculated in here. Like the local gradients of max pool is 0s and 1s, so they just copy the values from grad_in that is coming in? Although there are comments about the parameters top_diff, top_offset, bottom_offset; can somebody explain what are those (I'm a beginner)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right about the local gradients for max pool is `0`'s and `1`'s. However, if the same max value was propagated from two adjoining patches, then the corresponding gradient values has to be summed up and backpropped to the location of that max value. For example, consider a 1-D vector :

```
[x0 x1 x2]
```

Suppose you are running `MaxPool` with patch size `2` and stride `1`, and suppose that `max(x0, x1) = x1` and `max(x1, x2) = x1`. Then the output would be

```
[x1 x1]
```

Let's say the gradients coming in is `[g1 g2]`, then the gradients that have to be backpropped is

```
[0 g1+g2 0]
```

That's what you see the `cudaAtomicAdd` function call in the code you pointed out.

Comment: Hi @keveman, thank for your reply. now if I were to do a max unpool operation, which would take [x1 x1] and an argmax matrix [1 1] to unpool into [0 x1 0] with the patch size and stride you mentioned, how should I go about the max unpool backward? Does this make sense for a max unpool backward:
`int image_id = (index / top_offset); CudaAtomicAdd(bottom_diff + index, top_diff[mask[index] + image_id * top_offset]);`